# При использовании pywin32 для создания писем outlook в цикле, появляется "The MIT License (MIT)"

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, email, windows-10, pywin32

Есть небольшой скрипт, который запускается через планировщик заданий и отправляет письма из txt файлов. Поместите в папку с файлом любой (или несколько) txt файл с более 3-х строк (1- почта, 2 - тема, 3 - тело сообщения).
При запуске файла двойным щелчком, все отлично. Но если засунуть его в планировщик заданий, то письмо заполняется данными о лицензии. В файле письма создаются в цикле, если же цикл убрать, то все работает. Как мне обойти это ограничение? Поиск в интернете не дал результатов.

```
    """Модуль проверки ошибок"""
import win32com.client as win32
import os


def listdir():
    """Файлы дериктории собираем в список, отфильтровав только нужные
    """
    directory = str(os.getcwd())
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    doc = list(filter(lambda x: x[-4:] == '.txt', files))
    return doc

def Emailer(text, subject, recipient):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.Body = text
    mail.Display(False)
    # mail.Send()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in listdir():
        with open(i, encoding='UTF8') as f: ## Открываем файл
            my_lines = list(f) ## Помещаем в список.
        email = my_lines[0]
        tema = my_lines[1]
        message1 = ''.join(my_lines[2:])
        Emailer(message1, tema, email)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Два логичных вопроса: `listdir()` — listdir какой папки? `open(i` — открытие какого файла? Вполне логично предположить, что вы открыли файл, который содержит все эти строки

Comment: listdir() сохраняет в список все txt файлы в директории с файлом, open(i открывает каждый из этих файлов.

Comment: Ну вот среди этих файлов и оказался такой, который содержит эти строки

Comment: Действительно, функция listdir() возвращает папку C:\Windows\system32. Как тогда мне сделать, что бы читалась папка с файлом?

Comment: Если вы выполняете listdir текущей рабочей папки, то значит изменить текущую рабочую папку на ту, которая вам нужна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема была в том, что при запуске через планировщик заданий, основной папкой становится C:\Windows\system32.
Что бы этого избежать нужно везде указывать конкретную папку, в моём случае
`directory = str(os.getcwd())` - это не работает
`directory = "D:/"` - это работает (при этом её надо вынести за пределы функции)

`with open(i, encoding='UTF8') as f:` это меняем на

```
with open(f'{directory }{i}', encoding='UTF8') as f:
```

Comment: Если в конце `directory` не будет слэша, то случится ой, поэтому правильнее `os.path.join(directory, i)`